# Which Automation Framework provides an option to schedule runs?

Tags: testing, frameworks, automation, testcase, manual-testing

i want to use an automation framework/tool which can help me in scheduling my runs so that my test scripts can run automatically as per my desired time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should integrate with any [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) etc

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be dependent on any tool for scheduling your test runs. First you need to understand which file you need to execute your test, for example in selenium, test can be executed by running testng.xml on command line, you can simply create a vb script or batch file containing all the commands and use that batch file in Windows Scheduler.
You can find windows scheduler in Windows 7 at Control Panel - Administrative Tool - Windows Scheduler - Create Basic Schedule -- Here you can browse the your trigger file and run your test weekly, daily, monthly etcc... Hope this helps !

Thanks,
Pankaj.